# Samba won't let me view my shared folder (Ubuntu systems only)

Tags: samba

I have two Ubuntu laptops, 16.10 and 16.04, each with samba server and client installed via `sudo-apt get install`. I can see clearly in my Nautilus (Files) folder that `Windows Network` is there. From 16.04 I can click that and see my shared folder (it is a folder I have shared from 16.04). That's as I expected obviously. But when I click `Windows Network` in 16.10 I get the following, which hangs and does nothing. Any ideas what is wrong?

On both machines I have executed `sudo service smbd restart`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially solved this by replacing my 16.10 installation with 17.04 Zesty. This worked fine for a while, but then stopped working, so I checked out the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and for some reason something had been added just after WORKGROUP. So I **purged/removed** samba using `sudo apt-get purge samba` and then reinstalled `sudo apt-get install samba` which reset my `.conf` files and everything worked again. Hence, overall I can't be sure if it was 16.10 or something to do with the `.conf` file.